# conda thinks a package is installed, but it's not working. when I try to uninstall, it wants to remove 120+ other packages

Tags: python, conda, dask, package-managers

Like many others, I got myself into hot waters alternating between pip, conda, and even brew installs. I'm finally running into issues with a package that just won't run correctly after days of troubleshooting: dask.

I'm trying to uninstaall the dask package out for a fresh start, then reinstall. I ran `pip uninstall dask` first, and my plan was to then run `conda uninstall dask`, but the conda uninstall seems to want to take everything but the kitchen sink with it. Below is output if I begin to run `conda uninstall dask` (but decline conda's offer to proceed).

Why does conda want to remove 120+ packages just to remove dask? Can I ask conda to only remove dask, so I can then reinstall it?

```
$ conda uninstall dask

output:
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/username/anaconda3

  removed specs:
    - dask


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    sqlite-3.33.0              |       hffcf06c_0         2.5 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         2.5 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  anyio              pkgs/main/osx-64::anyio-2.2.0-py37hecd8cb5_1
  argcomplete        pkgs/main/noarch::argcomplete-1.12.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  argon2-cffi        pkgs/main/osx-64::argon2-cffi-20.1.0-py37h9ed2024_1
  async_generator    pkgs/main/osx-64::async_generator-1.10-py37h28b3542_0
  brotli             pkgs/main/osx-64::brotli-1.0.9-hb1e8313_2
  brotlipy           pkgs/main/osx-64::brotlipy-0.7.0-py37h9ed2024_1003
  charset-normalizer pkgs/main/noarch::charset-normalizer-2.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  debugpy            pkgs/main/osx-64::debugpy-1.5.1-py37he9d5cce_0
  fonttools          pkgs/main/noarch::fonttools-4.25.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  fsspec             pkgs/main/noarch::fsspec-2022.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  giflib             pkgs/main/osx-64::giflib-5.2.1-haf1e3a3_0
  json5              pkgs/main/noarch::json5-0.9.6-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  jupyter_server     pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyter_server-1.4.1-py37hecd8cb5_0
  jupyterlab_pygmen~ pkgs/main/noarch::jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-py_0
  jupyterlab_widgets pkgs/main/noarch::jupyterlab_widgets-1.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  lcms2              pkgs/main/osx-64::lcms2-2.12-hf1fd2bf_0
  libwebp            pkgs/main/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  libwebp-base       pkgs/main/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0
  matplotlib-inline  pkgs/main/noarch::matplotlib-inline-0.1.2-pyhd3eb1b0_2
  munkres            pkgs/main/noarch::munkres-1.1.4-py_0
  nbclassic          pkgs/main/noarch::nbclassic-0.2.6-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  nbclient           pkgs/main/noarch::nbclient-0.5.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  nest-asyncio       pkgs/main/noarch::nest-asyncio-1.5.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  prompt-toolkit     pkgs/main/noarch::prompt-toolkit-3.0.20-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sniffio            pkgs/main/osx-64::sniffio-1.2.0-py37hecd8cb5_1

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  _anaconda_depends-2019.03-py37_0
  alabaster-0.7.12-py37_0
  anaconda-custom-py37_1
  anaconda-project-0.8.2-py37_0
  appscript-1.1.0-py37h1de35cc_0
  asn1crypto-0.24.0-py37_0
  astroid-2.2.5-py37_0
  astropy-3.1.2-py37h1de35cc_0
  atomicwrites-1.3.0-py37_1
  backports-1.0-py37_1
  backports.os-0.1.1-py37_0
  backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py37_2
  bitarray-0.8.3-py37h1de35cc_0
  bkcharts-0.2-py37_0
  blosc-1.15.0-hd9629dc_0
  bokeh-1.0.4-py37_0
  boto-2.49.0-py37_0
  colorama-0.4.1-py37_0
  contextlib2-0.5.5-py37_0
  curl-7.64.0-ha441bb4_2
  cython-0.29.6-py37h0a44026_0
  dask-1.1.4-py37_1
  dbus-1.13.6-h90a0687_0
  docutils-0.14-py37_0
  et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py37_0
  expat-2.2.6-h0a44026_0
  fastcache-1.0.2-py37h1de35cc_2
  flask-1.0.2-py37_1
  get_terminal_size-1.0.0-h7520d66_0
  gettext-0.19.8.1-h15daf44_3
  gevent-1.4.0-py37h1de35cc_0
  glib-2.56.2-hd9629dc_0
  gmp-6.1.2-hb37e062_1
  gmpy2-2.0.8-py37h6ef4df4_2
  greenlet-0.4.15-py37h1de35cc_0
  h5py-2.9.0-py37h3134771_0
  hdf5-1.10.4-hfa1e0ec_0
  html5lib-1.0.1-py37_0
  imageio-2.5.0-py37_0
  imagesize-1.1.0-py37_0
  iniconfig-1.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  isort-4.3.16-py37_0
  itsdangerous-1.1.0-py37_0
  jbig-2.1-h4d881f8_0
  jdcal-1.4-py37_0
  jupyter-1.0.0-py37_7
  jupyter_console-6.0.0-py37_0
  keyring-23.4.0-py37hecd8cb5_0
  krb5-1.16.1-hddcf347_7
  lazy-object-proxy-1.3.1-py37h1de35cc_2
  libcurl-7.64.0-h051b688_2
  libcxxabi-4.0.1-hcfea43d_1
  libssh2-1.8.0-ha12b0ac_4
  llvmlite-0.28.0-py37h8c7ce04_0
  lzo-2.10-h362108e_2
  mccabe-0.6.1-py37_1
  more-itertools-6.0.0-py37_0
  mpc-1.1.0-h6ef4df4_1
  mpfr-4.0.1-h3018a27_3
  mpmath-1.1.0-py37_0
  multipledispatch-0.6.0-py37_0
  networkx-2.6.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  nltk-3.4-py37_1
  nose-1.3.7-py37_2
  numba-0.43.1-py37h6440ff4_0
  numpydoc-0.8.0-py37_0
  openpyxl-3.0.9-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pandoc-2.2.3.2-0
  path.py-11.5.0-py37_0
  pathlib2-2.3.3-py37_0
  patsy-0.5.1-py37_0
  pcre-8.43-h0a44026_0
  pep8-1.7.1-py37_0
  pluggy-1.0.0-py37hecd8cb5_0
  ply-3.11-py37_0
  prompt_toolkit-2.0.9-py37_0
  py-1.10.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pycodestyle-2.5.0-py37_0
  pycrypto-2.6.1-py37h1de35cc_9
  pycurl-7.43.0.2-py37ha12b0ac_0
  pyflakes-2.1.1-py37_0
  pylint-2.3.1-py37_0
  pyodbc-4.0.26-py37h0a44026_0
  pytables-3.5.1-py37h5bccee9_0
  pytest-6.2.5-py37hecd8cb5_2
  pytest-arraydiff-0.3-py37h39e3cac_0
  pytest-astropy-0.5.0-py37_0
  pytest-doctestplus-0.3.0-py37_0
  pytest-openfiles-0.3.2-py37_0
  pytest-remotedata-0.3.1-py37_0
  pywavelets-1.0.2-py37h1d22016_0
  qtawesome-0.5.7-py37_1
  qtconsole-4.4.3-py37_0
  rope-0.12.0-py37_0
  scikit-image-0.14.2-py37h0a44026_0
  scikit-learn-0.20.3-py37h27c97d8_0
  seaborn-0.9.0-py37_0
  simplegeneric-0.8.1-py37_2
  singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py37_0
  snappy-1.1.7-he62c110_3
  snowballstemmer-1.2.1-py37_0
  sortedcollections-1.1.2-py37_0
  sphinx-1.8.5-py37_0
  sphinxcontrib-1.0-py37_1
  sphinxcontrib-websupport-1.1.0-py37_1
  spyder-3.3.3-py37_0
  spyder-kernels-0.4.2-py37_0
  sqlalchemy-1.3.1-py37h1de35cc_0
  statsmodels-0.11.1-py37haf1e3a3_0
  sympy-1.3-py37_0
  tbb-2020.0-h04f5b5a_0
  toml-0.10.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  unicodecsv-0.14.1-py37_0
  unixodbc-2.3.7-h1de35cc_0
  werkzeug-0.14.1-py37_0
  wrapt-1.11.1-py37h1de35cc_0
  wurlitzer-1.0.2-py37_0
  xlrd-1.2.0-py37_0
  xlsxwriter-1.1.5-py37_0
  xlwings-0.15.4-py37_0
  xlwt-1.3.0-py37_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  anaconda-client                              1.7.2-py37_0 --> 1.9.0-py37hecd8cb5_0
  appnope                                      0.1.0-py37_0 --> 0.1.2-py37hecd8cb5_1001
  babel                pkgs/main/osx-64::babel-2.6.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::babel-2.9.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  backcall           pkgs/main/osx-64::backcall-0.1.0-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::backcall-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  beautifulsoup4     pkgs/main/osx-64::beautifulsoup4-4.7.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::beautifulsoup4-4.10.0-pyh06a4308_0
  bleach              pkgs/main/osx-64::bleach-3.1.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::bleach-4.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  bottleneck                           1.2.1-py37h1d22016_1 --> 1.3.2-py37hf1fa96c_1
  bzip2                                    1.0.6-h1de35cc_5 --> 1.0.8-h1de35cc_0
  cffi                                1.12.2-py37hb5b8e2f_1 --> 1.15.0-py37hca72f7f_0
  chardet                                      3.0.4-py37_1 --> 4.0.0-py37hecd8cb5_1003
  click                  pkgs/main/osx-64::click-7.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::click-8.0.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  conda-package-han~ conda-forge::conda-package-handling-1~ --> pkgs/main::conda-package-handling-1.7.3-py37h9ed2024_1
  cryptography                         2.6.1-py37ha12b0ac_0 --> 36.0.0-py37hf6deb26_0
  cycler             pkgs/main/osx-64::cycler-0.10.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::cycler-0.11.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  cytoolz                            0.9.0.1-py37h1de35cc_1 --> 0.11.0-py37haf1e3a3_0
  dask-core          pkgs/main/osx-64::dask-core-1.1.4-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::dask-core-2021.10.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  decorator          pkgs/main/osx-64::decorator-4.4.0-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::decorator-5.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  defusedxml         pkgs/main/osx-64::defusedxml-0.5.0-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::defusedxml-0.7.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  filelock           pkgs/main/osx-64::filelock-3.0.10-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::filelock-3.4.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  freetype                                 2.9.1-hb4e5f40_0 --> 2.11.0-hd8bbffd_0
  future                                      0.17.1-py37_0 --> 0.18.2-py37_1
  glob2                  pkgs/main/osx-64::glob2-0.6-py37_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch::glob2-0.7-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  heapdict           pkgs/main/osx-64::heapdict-1.0.0-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::heapdict-1.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  icu                                       58.2-h4b95b61_1 --> 58.2-h0a44026_3
  idna                    pkgs/main/osx-64::idna-2.8-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::idna-3.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  intel-openmp                                   2019.3-199 --> 2021.4.0-hecd8cb5_3538
  ipykernel                            5.1.0-py37h39e3cac_0 --> 6.4.1-py37hecd8cb5_1
  ipython                              7.4.0-py37h39e3cac_0 --> 7.29.0-py37h01d92e1_0
  ipython_genutils   pkgs/main/osx-64::ipython_genutils-0.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::ipython_genutils-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  ipywidgets         pkgs/main/osx-64::ipywidgets-7.4.2-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::ipywidgets-7.6.5-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  jedi                                        0.13.3-py37_0 --> 0.18.1-py37hecd8cb5_0
  jinja2               pkgs/main/osx-64::jinja2-2.10-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::jinja2-2.11.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  jpeg                                        9b-he5867d9_2 --> 9d-h9ed2024_0
  jsonschema         pkgs/main/osx-64::jsonschema-3.0.1-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::jsonschema-3.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_2
  jupyter_client     pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyter_client-5.2.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::jupyter_client-7.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  jupyter_core                                 4.4.0-py37_0 --> 4.9.1-py37hecd8cb5_0
  jupyterlab         pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyterlab-0.35.4-p~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::jupyterlab-3.2.1-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  jupyterlab_server  pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyterlab_server-0~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::jupyterlab_server-2.10.2-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  kiwisolver                           1.0.1-py37h0a44026_0 --> 1.3.1-py37h23ab428_0
  libarchive                               3.3.3-h786848e_5 --> 3.4.2-haa3ed63_0
  libedit                           3.1.20181209-hb402a30_0 --> 3.1.20210910-hca72f7f_0
  libffi                                   3.2.1-h475c297_4 --> 3.2.1-h0a44026_1007
  libiconv                                  1.15-hdd342a3_7 --> 1.16-h1de35cc_0
  liblief                                  0.9.0-h2a1bed3_2 --> 0.10.1-h0a44026_0
  libpng                                  1.6.36-ha441bb4_0 --> 1.6.37-ha441bb4_0
  libsodium                               1.0.16-h3efe00b_0 --> 1.0.18-h1de35cc_0
  libtiff                                 4.0.10-hcb84e12_2 --> 4.2.0-h87d7836_0
  libxml2                                  2.9.9-hab757c2_0 --> 2.9.12-hcdb78fc_0
  libxslt                                 1.1.33-h33a18ac_0 --> 1.1.34-h83b36ba_0
  locket                                       0.2.0-py37_1 --> 0.2.1-py37hecd8cb5_1
  lxml                                 4.3.2-py37hef8c89e_0 --> 4.7.1-py37h65b224f_1
  lz4-c                                  1.8.1.2-h1de35cc_0 --> 1.9.3-h23ab428_1
  markupsafe                           1.1.1-py37h1de35cc_0 --> 2.0.1-py37h9ed2024_0
  matplotlib                           3.0.3-py37h54f8f79_0 --> 3.5.0-py37hecd8cb5_0
  matplotlib-base    conda-forge::matplotlib-base-3.1.1-py~ --> pkgs/main::matplotlib-base-3.5.0-py37h4f681db_0
  mkl                                            2019.4-233 --> 2021.4.0-hecd8cb5_637
  mkl-service                          2.3.0-py37h9ed2024_0 --> 2.4.0-py37h9ed2024_0
  mkl_fft                             1.0.10-py37h5e564d8_0 --> 1.3.1-py37h4ab4a9b_0
  mkl_random                           1.0.2-py37h27c97d8_0 --> 1.2.2-py37hb2f4e1b_0
  msgpack-python                       0.6.1-py37h04f5b5a_1 --> 1.0.2-py37hf7b0b51_1
  nbconvert                                    5.4.1-py37_3 --> 6.3.0-py37hecd8cb5_0
  nbformat           pkgs/main/osx-64::nbformat-4.4.0-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::nbformat-5.1.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  ncurses                                    6.1-h0a44026_1 --> 6.3-hca72f7f_2
  notebook                                     5.7.8-py37_0 --> 6.4.6-py37hecd8cb5_0
  numexpr                              2.7.3-py37h16bde0e_0 --> 2.8.1-py37h2e5f0a9_0
  numpy                               1.19.2-py37h456fd55_0 --> 1.21.2-py37h4b4dc7a_0
  numpy-base                          1.19.2-py37hcfb5961_0 --> 1.21.2-py37he0bd621_0
  pandocfilters                                1.4.2-py37_1 --> 1.4.3-py37hecd8cb5_1
  parso                pkgs/main/osx-64::parso-0.3.4-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::parso-0.8.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  partd               pkgs/main/osx-64::partd-0.3.10-py37_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch::partd-1.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pexpect            pkgs/main/osx-64::pexpect-4.6.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::pexpect-4.8.0-pyhd3eb1b0_3
  pickleshare        pkgs/main/osx-64::pickleshare-0.7.5-p~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::pickleshare-0.7.5-pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  pillow                               5.4.1-py37hb68e598_0 --> 8.4.0-py37h98e4679_0
  pip                                         19.0.3-py37_0 --> 21.2.2-py37hecd8cb5_0
  pkginfo                                    1.5.0.1-py37_0 --> 1.7.1-py37hecd8cb5_0
  prometheus_client  pkgs/main/osx-64::prometheus_client-0~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::prometheus_client-0.12.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  psutil                               5.6.1-py37h1de35cc_0 --> 5.8.0-py37h9ed2024_1
  ptyprocess         pkgs/main/osx-64::ptyprocess-0.6.0-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::ptyprocess-0.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_2
  py-lief                              0.9.0-py37h1413db1_2 --> 0.10.1-py37haf313ee_0
  pycparser          pkgs/main/osx-64::pycparser-2.19-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::pycparser-2.21-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pygments           pkgs/main/osx-64::pygments-2.3.1-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::pygments-2.10.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pykdtree           conda-forge::pykdtree-1.3.1-py37h3b54~ --> pkgs/main::pykdtree-1.3.4-py37he3068b8_1002
  pyopenssl          pkgs/main/osx-64::pyopenssl-19.0.0-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::pyopenssl-21.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  pyparsing          pkgs/main/osx-64::pyparsing-2.3.1-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::pyparsing-3.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyrsistent                         0.14.11-py37h1de35cc_0 --> 0.18.0-py37hca72f7f_0
  pyshp                       conda-forge::pyshp-2.1.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main::pyshp-2.1.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pysocks                                      1.6.8-py37_0 --> 1.7.1-py37hecd8cb5_0
  python-dateutil    pkgs/main/osx-64::python-dateutil-2.8~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::python-dateutil-2.8.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  python-libarchive~ pkgs/main/osx-64::python-libarchive-c~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::python-libarchive-c-2.9-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  pytz                 pkgs/main/osx-64::pytz-2018.9-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::pytz-2021.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyyaml                                 5.1-py37h1de35cc_0 --> 6.0-py37hca72f7f_1
  pyzmq                               18.0.0-py37h0a44026_0 --> 22.3.0-py37he9d5cce_2
  qtpy                  pkgs/main/osx-64::qtpy-1.7.0-py37_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch::qtpy-1.10.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  requests           pkgs/main/osx-64::requests-2.21.0-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::requests-2.27.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  ruamel_yaml                        0.15.46-py37h1de35cc_0 --> 0.15.100-py37h9ed2024_0
  scipy                                1.2.1-py37h1410ff5_0 --> 1.7.3-py37h8c7af03_0
  send2trash         pkgs/main/osx-64::send2trash-1.5.0-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::send2trash-1.8.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  setuptools                                  40.8.0-py37_0 --> 58.0.4-py37hecd8cb5_0
  six                   pkgs/main/osx-64::six-1.12.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::six-1.16.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sortedcontainers   pkgs/main/osx-64::sortedcontainers-2.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::sortedcontainers-2.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  soupsieve          pkgs/main/osx-64::soupsieve-1.8-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::soupsieve-2.3.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sqlite                                  3.27.2-ha441bb4_0 --> 3.33.0-hffcf06c_0
  tblib                pkgs/main/osx-64::tblib-1.3.2-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::tblib-1.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  terminado                                    0.8.1-py37_1 --> 0.9.4-py37hecd8cb5_0
  testpath           pkgs/main/osx-64::testpath-0.4.2-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::testpath-0.5.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  tk                                       8.6.8-ha441bb4_0 --> 8.6.11-h7bc2e8c_0
  toolz                pkgs/main/osx-64::toolz-0.9.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::toolz-0.11.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  tornado                              6.0.2-py37h1de35cc_0 --> 6.1-py37h9ed2024_0
  traitlets          pkgs/main/osx-64::traitlets-4.3.2-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::traitlets-5.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  urllib3            pkgs/main/osx-64::urllib3-1.24.3-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::urllib3-1.26.7-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  wcwidth            pkgs/main/osx-64::wcwidth-0.1.7-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::wcwidth-0.2.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  wheel               pkgs/main/osx-64::wheel-0.33.1-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::wheel-0.37.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  widgetsnbextension                           3.4.2-py37_0 --> 3.5.1-py37_0
  xz                                       5.2.4-h1de35cc_4 --> 5.2.5-h1de35cc_0
  yaml                                     0.1.7-hc338f04_2 --> 0.2.5-haf1e3a3_0
  zeromq                                   4.3.1-h0a44026_3 --> 4.3.4-h23ab428_0
  zict                  pkgs/main/osx-64::zict-0.1.4-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::zict-2.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  zlib                                    1.2.11-h1de35cc_3 --> 1.2.11-h4dc903c_4
  zstd                                     1.3.7-h5bba6e5_0 --> 1.4.9-h322a384_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  owslib                    conda-forge::owslib-0.19.1-py_0 --> pkgs/main::owslib-0.18.0-py_0
  proj4              conda-forge::proj4-5.2.0-h6de7cb9_1006 --> pkgs/main::proj4-5.2.0-h0a44026_1
  pyepsg              conda-forge/noarch::pyepsg-0.4.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main/osx-64::pyepsg-0.4.0-py37_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  pycosat                              0.6.3-py37h1de35cc_0 --> 0.6.3-py37h9ed2024_0
  pyqt                                 5.9.2-py37h655552a_2 --> 5.6.0-py37h655552a_6
  qt                                       5.9.7-h468cd18_1 --> 5.6.3-h1d42b2f_0
  sip                                 4.19.8-py37h0a44026_0 --> 4.18.1-py37h23ab428_2
  xmltodict                                     0.12.0-py_0 --> 0.12.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend to uninstall your current anaconda, then reinstall miniconda and instead of installing everything into base, create an environment for every distinct project... That way you reduce the risk of breaking stuff and if you do, you can just recreate the environment that is broken

Comment: This is the intended behavior of [`conda remove`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html), it's removing all dependencies of `dask` as well. As the answer suggests, using `--force` should work.

Comment: Thanks, these are both helpful comments. Dask is something I only just installed, and I'm having trouble understanding how all these packages could depend on it . . . like, why would curl and jupyter depend on a package that's built to extend pandas?

Comment: note in the spec conda is also installing and updating a large number of packages. it's possible that uninstalling dask released a couple constraints, so now conda has re-calculated the set of dependencies to use given your remaining spec. you *can* use `--force`, but you could also just let conda do it's job :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `conda remove dask --force`

Per [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html), --force forces removal of a package without removing packages that depend on it. Using this option will usually leave your environment in a broken and inconsistent state.